# boolean cannot be dereferenced in functional programming java

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I'm quite new in functional programming in Java. I was just practising creating some easy methods but I got an error here:

```
public void printCountSightingsOf(String animal)
{
    sightings.stream()
             .filter(s -> s.getAnimal().equalsIgnoreCase(animal) 
             .map(sa -> sa.getCount())
             .reduce(0, (total, s) -> total + s));
    System.out.println(sightings);
}
```

It should get a list of sightings of animals in a park from a file and convert it to a stream. Then it should filter that list in order to retrieve sightings of a specific animal only. Then the map function should transform that list into a list of type int where each element is the number of times that that animal has been seen by someone. Eventually, it should reduce that list into a unique sum and print that number out.
The error is on the .map line. It gives me this error :

> Boolean cannot be dereferenced. WHYYYYY? XD

Comment: your reduction can be improved to `.mapToInt(sa -> sa.getCount())
                .reduce(0, (total, s) -> total + s);` to avoid boxing/unboxing... or better `.mapToInt(sa -> sa.getCount())
                .sum();`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is missing a closing bracket in the line before `.map`:

```
sightings.stream()
         .filter(s -> s.getAnimal().equalsIgnoreCase(animal) 
         // missing bracket                            here ^
         .map(sa -> sa.getCount())
         .reduce(0, (total, s) -> total + s));
         // redundant bracket          here ^
```

Correct code is

```
sightings.stream()
         .filter(s -> s.getAnimal().equalsIgnoreCase(animal)) 
         .mapToInt(sa -> sa.getCount())
         .sum();
```

Comment: and there's an extra `)` after the `reduce` parenthesis.

Comment: @IllyaKysil For a perfect answer, you should also show the optimization [commented by Aomine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566551/boolean-cannot-be-dereferenced-in-functional-programming-java#comment93998959_53566551): `.mapToInt(sa -> sa.getCount()) .sum();`